# VB.net Split with <>/ characters not working

Tags: vb.net, string, split

I've always wondered why I'm unable to split a string with `<>/` etc.

For example, I am trying to split the string below:

```
<h3 class="r"><a href="https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://www.site.me/&ei=C2z3UqCeO4mrhQfT_oGQAg&usg=AFQjCNEnOMh79FnzOZLXjrvhaf5jAH_aog&sig2=AnVKWZvmdCXGRU-EcbTzFA" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNEnOMh79FnzOZLXjrvhaf5jAH_aog','AnVKWZvmdCXGRU-EcbTzFA','0CCgQFjAA','','',event)" data-href="http://www.site.me/">www.site.me <em>text</em> <b>...</b></a></h3>
```

I have 10 of these `h3 class="r"` attributes on the page.

So to get the first attribute I tried the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
Dim gurl As String = (Split(googlepage, "<h3 class=""r"">")(1).Split("</h3>")(0))
```

The same goes with the one below.

```
Dim gurl as String = (Split(googleplage, "<cite>")(1).split("</cite")(0))
```

It doesn't give any error, but it doesn't get anything. When I try to output it in a messagebox it shows nothing. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you seen the HtmlAgilityPack (on nugget)?

Comment: Haven't seen that, but woulden't it be able to just use the normal split. But I would also like to know why you can't split with those chars. But thanks though!

Comment: You can split with those characters - worth noting that you're using [two](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) [different](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) Split functions there - are you using `Option Strict` as you may be having some implicit conversions tripping you up?

Comment: Do you mind showing an example of how to split a html source with <cite></cite> ? Thanks.

Comment: I managed to solve it! But thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, bit slow to type on my tablet, but the following demonstrates several ways of using [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Option Strict On

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim googlepage As String = "<h3 class=""r""><a href=""https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://www.site.me/&ei=C2z3UqCeO4mrhQfT_oGQAg&usg=AFQjCNEnOMh79FnzOZLXjrvhaf5jAH_aog&sig2=AnVKWZvmdCXGRU-EcbTzFA"" onmousedown=""return rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNEnOMh79FnzOZLXjrvhaf5jAH_aog','AnVKWZvmdCXGRU-EcbTzFA','0CCgQFjAA','','',event)"" data-href=""http://www.site.me/"">www.site.me <em>text</em> <b>...</b></a></h3>" & _
        "<h3 class=""r""><a href=""https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://www.site.me/&ei=C2z3UqCeO4mrhQfT_oGQAg&usg=AFQjCNEnOMh79FnzOZLXjrvhaf5jAH_aog&sig2=AnVKWZvmdCXGRU-EcbTzFA"" onmousedown=""return rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNEnOMh79FnzOZLXjrvhaf5jAH_aog','AnVKWZvmdCXGRU-EcbTzFA','0CCgQFjAA','','',event)"" data-href=""http://www.site.me/"">www.site.me <em>text</em> <b>...</b></a></h3>" & _
        "<h3 class=""r""><a href=""https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://www.site.me/&ei=C2z3UqCeO4mrhQfT_oGQAg&usg=AFQjCNEnOMh79FnzOZLXjrvhaf5jAH_aog&sig2=AnVKWZvmdCXGRU-EcbTzFA"" onmousedown=""return rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNEnOMh79FnzOZLXjrvhaf5jAH_aog','AnVKWZvmdCXGRU-EcbTzFA','0CCgQFjAA','','',event)"" data-href=""http://www.site.me/"">www.site.me <em>text</em> <b>...</b></a></h3>" & _
        "<h3 class=""r""><a href=""https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://www.site.me/&ei=C2z3UqCeO4mrhQfT_oGQAg&usg=AFQjCNEnOMh79FnzOZLXjrvhaf5jAH_aog&sig2=AnVKWZvmdCXGRU-EcbTzFA"" onmousedown=""return rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNEnOMh79FnzOZLXjrvhaf5jAH_aog','AnVKWZvmdCXGRU-EcbTzFA','0CCgQFjAA','','',event)"" data-href=""http://www.site.me/"">www.site.me <em>text</em> <b>...</b></a></h3>"

        Dim headings = googlepage.Split({"</h3>"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
        For Each heading In headings
            ' No point splitting on <H3...> as we've already split on end tag, so for illustration, I'll split on '<' to give a list of nodes
            Dim nodes = heading.Split("<"c)
            For Each node In nodes
                Dim parts = node.Split(">"c)
                Dim attributes = parts(0).Split({vbTab, " ", vbCr, vbLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) ' First "attribute is the tag name"

                For i As Integer = 0 To attributes.Length - 1
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", If(i = 0, "Tag", "Attribute"), attributes(i))
                Next
                Console.WriteLine("Contect: {0}", If(parts.Length > 1, parts(1), "(empty)"))
            Next
            Console.WriteLine("Next heading:")
        Next
    End Sub

End Module
```

Of course, there's no reason to write your own HTML parser though, as the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) does it so well